# Pandas Remove Outliers from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am following the below logic,

```
from scipy import stats
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3))
df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

My df has multiple columns included value1, value2, description, task, etc. so I am having trouble dealing with A) half of my columns being text and B) removing outliers ONLY from the value1 column. I know the above code would remove rows that have outliers in either value1 or 2 - how would I adjust this to only look at value1?

UPDATED CODE:

```
for y in yvar:
    temp = combo
    temp = temp[(temp['Financial Metric'] == y) & (temp['Financial Value'] != 0)]
    temp = temp.loc[np.abs(stats.zscore(temp['Financial Value'])) < 3]
    for x in xvar:
        temp2 = temp
        temp2 = temp2[(temp2['External Metric'] == x) & (temp2['External Value'] != 0)]
        temp2 = temp2.loc[np.abs(stats.zscore(temp2['External Value'])) < 3]
        c = len(temp2.index)
        r = temp2['Financial Value'].corr(temp2['External Value'])
        col1.append(y)
        col2.append(x)
        col3.append(r)
        col4.append(c)
        temp2.plot(x ='External Value', y='Financial Value', kind = 'scatter')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loc` to filter the dataframe based on only the value1 column like this

```
df.loc[np.abs(stats.zscore(df['value1'])) < 3]
```

Comment: This runs for me, but it doesn't seem to do anything... The resulting scatter plot still shows that dot way up top which I'd assume is an outlier. Thoughts?

Comment: @RCarmody how do you run it? When you plot the data you need to make sure you plot the filtered data, .loc does not replace the original dataframe.